# Group By with syntax error

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

This shows up as NULL.

```
SELECT Gender, SUM( DISTINCT Freq ) AS TotalApp, 
(
    SELECT SUM( Freq ) 
    FROM ucbadmissions
    WHERE Admit = 'Rejected'
    IN (
        SELECT Admit
        FROM ucbadmissions
       )
) AS AdmRate
FROM ucbadmissions
GROUP BY Gender
```

This shows as the error.

```
SELECT Gender, SUM( DISTINCT Freq ) AS TotalApp, 
(
    SELECT  SUM( Freq ) 
    FROM ucbadmissions
    WHERE Admit != 'Rejected'
    Group By Gender
) AS AdmRate
FROM ucbadmissions
Group By Gender
```

Example of the table.

> Admit    Gender  Dept  Freq
>   Admitted Male     A 512 
>   Rejected Male     A 313 
>   Admitted Female   A 89 
>   Rejected Female   A 19 
>   Rejected Female   B 8 
>   Admitted Female   B 17 
>   Rejected Male     B 207 
>   Admitted Male     B 353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT      Gender, SUM(Freq) AS TotalApp,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Admit = 'Admitted' THEN Freq ELSE 0 END) / SUM(Freq) AS AdmitRate
FROM        ucbAdmissions
GROUP BY    Gender
```

Comment: Thanks you it works, we havent really learn case yet so that's why this was a little hard.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  Gender, 
  SUM(Freq) AS TotalApp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Admit = 'Rejected' THEN 0 else Freq END) AS AdmRate
FROM ucbadmissions
GROUP BY Gender
```

This will return the gender plus the total number of applications plus the number of successfull applications per gender.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, we have to add up all the frequency for that row. Like the Totalapp would be you add up all the male application, and AdmRate would be the admitted male/totalapp. If that make more sense thank you for helping too.